# solr import a csv file error

Tags: csv, solr, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file into SOLR 4.8.1 using CURL. It's giving me an error that it's expecting field names in the CSV input. I'm importing the books.csv file that is packaged with SOLR in the example file!

Anyone know of the top of their head what is wrong w/ this? Thanks.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/csv --data-binary @books.csv -H 'Content-type:text/csv; charset=utf-8'

Warning: Couldn't read data from file "books.csv", this makes an empty POST.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">400</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int></lst>
<lst name="error"><str name="msg">Expected fieldnames in CSV input</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

books.csv first four lines.

```
id,cat,name,price,inStock,author,series_t,sequence_i,genre_s
0553573403,book,A Game of Thrones,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553579908,book,A Clash of Kings,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",2,fantasy
055357342X,book,A Storm of Swords,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",3,fantasy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. File was in wrong directory.

Comment: Kindly tell us which is the right directory. Thanks